# Unresolved reference 'Payload' after upgrading android jetpack workmanager to version 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I updated the android workmanager to version 1.0.1 but got a compile error after syncing with an error on the Payload object (which is returned by the doWork method of the Worker class) highlighted in red and reading: 'unresolved reference Payload'

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, according to the official docs ([here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work)) on the latest update to Workmanager, the doWork method should return a 'Result' object and not a 'Payload' object like below

```
class UploadWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters)
    : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {

            // Get the input
            val imageUriInput = getInputData().getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_URI)
            // TODO: validate inputs.
            // Do the work
            val response = uploadFile(imageUriInput)

            // Create the output of the work
            val outputData = workDataOf(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_URL to response.imageUrl)

            // Return the output
            return Result.success(outputData)

    }
}
```